# How to update threejs texture with movable text and logos

Tags: javascript, three.js, fabricjs

I'm trying to create a 3d customizer using threejs, right now i also using fabric js to add texts and set the fabricjs canvas as texture like this

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1));

var canvasTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(cnvs);
canvasTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
canvasTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
canvasTexture.repeat.set(2, 2);

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 20, 20);
geometry.vertices.forEach(v => {
  v.z = Math.cos(v.x) * Math.sin(-v.y * 0.5) * 0.5;
});
geometry.computeFaceNormals();
geometry.computeVertexNormals();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: canvasTexture,
  metalness: 0.25,
  roughness: 0.25
}));
scene.add(mesh);

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cnvs', {
  backgroundColor: 'white'
});
canvas.on("after:render", function() {
  mesh.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
});

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  left: 50,
  top: 128,
  stroke: '#aaf',
  strokeWidth: 5,
  fill: '#faa',
  selectable: false,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(rect);

function animateRandom() {
  var randomX = THREE.Math.randInt(50, 206);
  var randomY = THREE.Math.randInt(50, 206);

  rect.animate({
    left: randomX,
    top: randomY
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
    easing: fabric.util.ease.easeOutExpo
  })
}

var text = new fabric.IText('Three.js\n+\nFaBric.js', {
  fontSize: 40,
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  left: 128,
  top: 128,
  angle: 30,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  shadow: 'blue -5px 6px 5px',
  styles: {
    0: {
      0: {
        fontSize: 60,
        fontFamily: 'Impact',
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        fill: 'orange'
      }
    },
    1: {
      0: {
        fill: "blue"
      }
    },
    2: {
      0: {
        textBackgroundColor: 'red'
      },
      2: {
        fill: 'fuchsia',
        stroke: 'orange',
        strokeWidth: 1
      }
    }
  }
});
text.setSelectionStyles({
  fontStyle: 'italic',
  fill: '',
  stroke: 'red',
  strokeWidth: 2
}, 1, 5);
canvas.add(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

animateRandom();
setInterval(animateRandom, 1000);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;
render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  mesh.lookAt(Math.cos(time * 0.314) * 20, Math.sin(time * 0.157) * 10, 40);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="cnvs" height="256" width="256"></canvas>
</div>
```

You can access it through jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/rr1bsfsj)

and the result is like this

[image]

i wanted to hide the fabricjs canvas and the user able to change its positions directly from the 3d object, here's my reference https://www.owayo.com/konfigurator_html/index.php?sport=football&product=shirts_f3&lang=en&land=us#

does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: SVG stands for "Scalable Vector Graphics", which means you're allowed to scale it down. Look at its properties and change it from 2048 to whatever resolution you wish.

Comment: yes i've tried it but, i think i shouldve change the uv map also since when i change the svg from 2k to 256 it'll be blurry when its on the 3d mesh, i'll updated my post

Comment: The UVs don't do anything to improve resolution. All they do is indicate which corner of the texture goes where. If 256 is too blurry, try 512, or 1024.

Comment: i can't use larger than 256 cause the fabricjs canvas is shown on the html, if i change to 1024 the screen will filled with fabricjs canvas, idont want that. also i think ishould've try another method but idk which one

Comment: if u look at this https://www.owayo.com/konfigurator_html/index.php?sport=football&product=shirts_f3&lang=en&land=us# they dont use fabricjs canvas to add text

Comment: The size of the canvas on your page doesn't have to match its pixel dimensions. For example, you could scale your canvas down with CSS: `transform: scale(0.5);`, or set its CSS width/height to be smaller than its pixel width/height: `<canvas width="1024" height="1024" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" />`

Comment: there i insert my currect development, the text and shapes r so big on the 3d model, should i change the 3d model size?/